# AngularJS $formatters and $parsers modifying model incorrectly with input[number] arrows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to get a numeric input field working to allow the user to specify frequencies in any units they wish (Hz, kHz, MHz, or GHz). The model should always stored the actual frequency in Hz, regardless of the user's preference for display and input.

My desired behavior is as follows:

- Always store value in Hz
- Always display value in kHz
- Convert user's edits from kHz to Hz when updating model
- Properly respect min/max values (2kHz - 18 MHz)
- Step input field in steps of '1', which update the model in 1000 Hz steps.

What I'm actually experiencing:

- If I type "2" in the input, the model is properly updated to 2000 Hz and the validators are all good to go
- If I then click the up spinner arrow (or press the up arrow key), the value snaps to 2000 in the input field, and the model is set to 2000000 Hz.

How can I ensure that the spinner arrows and arrow keys function correctly?

I have a Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/HKnMRsRCfAMWXaZImCsM?p=preview) that simulates this behavior in kHz.

My HTML code is:

```
<body ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Controller">
  <label>Frequency (kHz):
    <input magnitude-converter type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
           min="2000" max="18000000" step="1" required>
 </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
      Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.number">
      Not valid number!</span>
  </div>
  <tt>value (Hz) = {{example.value}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
</body>
```

My JS code is:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
      name: 'Naomi',
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };
  }])
  .directive('magnitudeConverter', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        var parser = function(value) {
          var parsedValue = value * 1000;
          return parsedValue;
        };
        var formatter = function(value) {
          var formattedValue = value / 1000;
          return formattedValue;
        };
        ngModel.$parsers.push(parser);
        ngModel.$formatters.push(formatter);
      }
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have specified the `min="2000"` in the `input` element and this is the feature of the modern browsers that they will set the value to the minimum value if the specified value is wrong.

To fix this problem, you can either change the `min="2000"` to `min="2"` (since you are converting it) or remove the `min` & `max` constraint and add a custom validator (introduced in Angular 1.3.0) like this:

```
ngModel.$validators.myFooValidation = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    return modelValue >= 2000 && modelValue <= 18000000;
}
```

And later display the error:

```
<div ng-show="myForm.input.$error.myFooValidation">
   Value should be between 2 to 18000
</div>
```

Comment: Updating the min/max value doesn't work. Setting the min to "2" and the max to "18000" only allows values 2-18 to work in the input field. The 2 is the minimum in the display, and 18000 is the maximum in the model.  I need the min/max to be 2-18000 in the input itself.  I'll give the custom validator a try though.

Comment: The custom validator did the trick! I left the min and max attributes in the HTML, but deleted the min and max validators in the directive's $validators collection. Now I can validate the input based on the modelValue, while also letting the browser enforce the min and max values appropriately when using the arrow buttons/keys.